# Excel 2010 SUM function not recognizing negative number that is referenced to another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, formulas

I am working with a workbook in Excel 2010, this workbook has 2 sheets lets called them shee1 and sheet2, on sheet2 I have a positive value in J7 (2000.00), in sheet1 I am calling that value from cell a1 with a formula "-Sheet2!J7" and it is displying a value of (2000.00) which would be a negative value, then I proceed with writing a sum() function in a4 sheet1 =SUM(A1:A3) where I get a result of 0. I belive I should be getting a value of -2000.00 but Excel is not recognizing the referenced cell A1. HELP!!!!

Comment: What does the formula builder show when you put the cursor in the SUM part of the formula and press the fx button next to the formula? It will show you what numbers it is adding together to get the 0 value, in brackets to the right of the first parameter. That'll be a clue to what's happening...

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for data from sheet1, while your data is on sheet2. You should write:

```
"-Sheet2!J7"
```

into the A1 cell of Sheet1.

Comment: My apologies The formula in sheet1 looks like this =-Sheet2!j7

Comment: In Sheet1 it is displaying the value of (2,000.00) which means it is a negative value, the problem will be with the sum function which is not taking the value of A1 therefore it is giving up a result of 0 where the correct result would have to be -2,000.00

Answer (score 0):

Just want to know

> from cell a1 with a formula "-Sheet1!J7"

it should be "-Sheet2!J7" right, correct me If I am wrong.  And I am getting proper answer as -2000

I hope you have formatted All the cells similar to A1 i.e. () for negative numbers. I hope you would have done it already

Comment: Yes all cells have the same format and I keep getting the result of =SUM(A1:A3) with a value of 0 instead of -2,000.00

Comment: @AlfredoA. Just check this file.  http://snk.to/f-chkm2upz
Downlaod the file, This is similar to what u said. Just check